# RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration does not support Pub/Sub because of missing Pub/Sub message propagation across individual servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

i want to apply `spring-session-data-redis` to my `spring boot` project.

but printed log `Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms`

exception message is `Pub/Sub connections not supported with Master/Replica configurations`

my redis configuration is

```
public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration configuration = new RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration(
    MASTER_HOST, MASTER_PORT);
    configuration.addNode(SLAVE_HOST, SLAVE_PORT);
             
    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig =
            LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA_PREFERRED).build();
        
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(configuration, clientConfig);
}
```

developed in `aws` environment.
and my redis environment is write to master, read from replica

So we applied `RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration` according to the document below.

> For environments reporting non-public addresses through the INFO
> command (for example, when using AWS), use
> RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration instead of
> RedisStandaloneConfiguration.

but, it does not support `Pub/Sub` according to the document below.

> Please note that RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration does not
> support Pub/Sub because of missing Pub/Sub message propagation across
> individual servers.

have any good ideas?

**the strange thing is**

printed log `Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms`

but, It works well.(save and select session at `redis`)

**additional infomation:**

trying to connect `Pub/Sub` by this.

`org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration`

```
@Bean
public RedisMessageListenerContainer springSessionRedisMessageListenerContainer(
        RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository) {
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(this.redisConnectionFactory);
    if (this.redisTaskExecutor != null) {
        container.setTaskExecutor(this.redisTaskExecutor);
    }
    if (this.redisSubscriptionExecutor != null) {
        container.setSubscriptionExecutor(this.redisSubscriptionExecutor);
    }
    container.addMessageListener(sessionRepository,
            Arrays.asList(new ChannelTopic(sessionRepository.getSessionDeletedChannel()),
                    new ChannelTopic(sessionRepository.getSessionExpiredChannel())));
    container.addMessageListener(sessionRepository,
            Collections.singletonList(new PatternTopic(sessionRepository.getSessionCreatedChannelPrefix() + "*")));
    return container;
}
```